# Fragments MediaPlayer and moving back

Tags: android-fragments

I've got an app with Navigation Drawer using fragments. From One of the fragments that lists all tracks, I try to run a media player and show it's associated lyrics. But I'm unable to handle the back button of this fragment.

What I have done here only navigates back to the previous fragment. But I'm unable to click the ListView items after coming back and I'm also unable to click on my nav drawer in the mediaplayer or once I move back from the mediaplayer fragment. Anyone with any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
package com.myapp.slidingmenu;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.MediaController.MediaPlayerControl;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.myapp.myplayer.R;

public class PlayTrackFragment extends Fragment implements MediaPlayerControl {

protected static final Fragment PlayTrackFragment = null;

public PlayTrackFragment(){}
private MediaController mMediaController;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
AssetFileDescriptor fd = null;
int iDispatchCounter = 1; 
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_playtrack, container, false);


    Bundle args = getArguments();
     if (args  != null && args.containsKey("id_User"))
     {
         String userId = args.getString("id_User");
         Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(),userId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    WebView wv;  
    wv = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webViewPlayTrack);  
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/traditions.html");  
    wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    wv.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    //AssetFileDescriptor fd = expansionFile.getAssetFileDescriptor(mytracks[trackTitle].toString()+".mp3");
    AssetFileDescriptor fd = null;
    try {
        fd = getActivity().getAssets().openFd("aa01.mp3");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (fd == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "Expansion File Not Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //return;
    }

    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaController = new MediaController(rootView.getContext()){
        @Override
        public void hide() {
            this.show(0);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && iDispatchCounter == 1)
            {
                iDispatchCounter++;
                   rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                   rootView.requestFocus();
                   if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()){ mMediaPlayer.pause();}
                   //mMediaPlayer = null;
                   //mMediaController.hide();
                   mMediaController.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   mMediaController = null;
                HomeFragment homefragment = new HomeFragment();
                PlayTrackFragment playtrackfragment = new PlayTrackFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getFragmentManager();

                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, homefragment).commit();
                fragmentTransaction2.remove(playtrackfragment).commit();


                //fragmentTransaction.commit();
                //mMediaPlayer.stop();
                //mMediaPlayer = null;
                //mMediaController = null;
                //getActivity().finish();
                //getActivity().onBackPressed();
                //Todo: make finish work
                //return true;
                //Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(),"Inside onDispatchKey",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i((String) getTag(), "onDispatch keyCode: " + event);
                //getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }

    };

    //Original Lines
    //mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(PlayTrack.this);


    mMediaController.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(40, 40, 80));
    mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(PlayTrackFragment.this);
    mMediaController.setAnchorView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutPlayTrack));
    mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);


    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource( fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(),fd.getLength());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mMediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


       mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        getActivity().setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                        mMediaController.show(0);
                    }
                });
            }
        });        




       /*rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

                    //mMediaController.show();
                    //do something
                }
                return true;
            }
    });*/

       /*rootView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
       rootView.requestFocus();
       rootView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                 Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(),"Inside onKey",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Log.i(getTag(), "onKey keyCode: " + keyCode);
                if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ) {
                        Log.i(getTag(), "onKey Back listener is working!!!");
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });*/


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    int percentage = (mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() * 100) / mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
    return percentage;
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null){return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();}
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        mMediaPlayer.pause();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {
    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
}

@Override
public void start() {
    mMediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: You should only provide a **minimal working example** when posting not working code.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I can hide the MediaController in the onDetach of the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mMediaController.hide();
    super.onDetach();
}
```

But there is still one problem. Although I can pull out my sliding drawer menu, I cannot click it. The MediaController seems to be on top of everything. How can I fix this please?